# Where to find good templates for mathematical proofs?

Tags: templates, proof-package, mathematics

Where can we find very good examples of templates for mathematical proofs using LaTeX?

Specially if we would aim to send something for the *Annals of Mathematics*?

Let's say, by hypothesis, that we have a good content to show, which template could we use so that every professional mathematician that reads the article / proof will be satisfied with the format / presentation of the ideas shown?

Comment: In general, you write your paper in LaTeX using the [amsmath](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) package. Once you've decided on a journal to submit your paper to, go to their website and find the guidelines they require. For Annals of Mathematics, they're [here](https://annals.math.princeton.edu/submission-guidelines) where you're told [aomart](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/aomart) package. Overleaf has a template [here](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-aomart-class/fzpbmyqcctjn). Journals can be particular be ready to adjust.

Comment: If your document has several theorem-like environments (e.g.., theorems, lemmas, propositions, corollaries, etc), it's almost a "must" to load either the `amsthm` or the `ntheorem` package. The former also provides an environment called `proof`, which automatically inserts a suitable QED symbol when `\end{proof}` is reached.

Comment: If you want pretty instead of professional, I would go with tcolorbox.